# PHP does not get values from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been searching through all the answers here but i can't get it to work.
I want to send two integer values from ajax to php.

Here is the ajax part:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){ 
          var id_user=$(this).filter(':checked').val();
          var stringname=$(this).attr('name'); 
          var substr = stringname.split('_'); 
          var id_paper=substr[1];
            alert('User_id is: '+id_user +'. And paper_id is: '+id_paper);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/expositor.php", 
            data: {ID_ponencia: id_paper, ID_Participante: id_user},
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//type of response
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            //dataType: "json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                alert('This is AJAX. The following is about to be sent. paper:'+id_paper+' user: '+ id_user);
            },
            success:function(response){
                var msj='#msj_'+id_paper;
                $(msj).append(response);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
          });
    });
});
```

I have tried with the commented parts of dataType and contentType and it doesn't work either.

Here is the php code.

```
    if(isset($_POST["ID_ponencia"]) && !empty($_POST['ID_ponencia']) && isset($_POST['ID_participante']) && !empty($_POST['ID_ponencia'])) 
{
    $ID_participante=$_POST['ID_participante'];
    $ID_ponencia=$_POST['ID_ponencia'];
    echo ('<p style="color: green;">Success! ☺</p>');
}else{
    //Output error
    echo ('<p style="color: red;">error!</p>');
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 There has been an error!');
    exit();
}
```

The php is working fine, since i have tested an html form posting to that php script and i get the successfull message. However, from the ajax script i get the 500 error.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried watching the request / response cycle using your browser's console tools? That should reveal any errors in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ajax is setting param of ID_Participante (capital P), but php is checking for ID_participante (lowercase p).

Also, you're checking if ID_ponencia is not empty twice...think you meant for the second one to be checking ID_participante.